# Could a Muggle become a Secret Keeper of Fidelius Charm?

Tags: harry-potter

Or is a magical person necessary for this charm to work?

Comment: A guess: Probably. I don't recall anything disallowing it.

Comment: Have you done any research into your problem? Anything that may have triggered this thought? Would the answer somehow solve a problem you were having? Or is this just a random thought you had?

Comment: I'd say no. It is a charm, magic in which the secret keeper serves as an active participant, a keeper. Muggles probably can't do it and cant swear the unbreakable vow. They can be only passive (victims) of charms or curses.

Comment: VTLO because of "We don't know" policy, yes bad policy, but that's what it is.

Comment: I fail to see how this is opinion-based. Either it has an answer or it doesn't. No opinion required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Probably Not.

We have no specific info on the Fidelius charm, but there is something else that is similar (and yes, I am going into headcanon here, but it's all we have): The unnamed charm that protects magical buildings from being seen:

> "It was a tiny, grubby-looking pub. **If Hagrid hadn't pointed it out,
>   Harry wouldn't have noticed it was there**. The people hurrying by didn't
>   glance at it. Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the
>   record shop on the other as if they couldn't see the Leaky Cauldron at
>   all. In fact, Harry had the most peculiar feeling that only he and
>   Hagrid could see it. Before he could mention this, Hagrid had steered
>   him inside."

This quote tells me that the Leaky Cauldron charm is similar to the Fidelius charm. Compare:

> Harry thought, and no sooner had he reached the part about number
>   twelve, Grimmauld Place, than a battered door emerged out of
>   nowhere between numbers eleven and thirteen, followed swiftly by
>   dirty walls and grimy windows. It was as though an extra house had
>   inflated, pushing those on either side out of its way. Harry gaped at it.
>   The stereo in number eleven thudded on. Apparently the Muggles inside
>   hadn’t even felt anything.

We also know that in a Fidelius charm, when the secret-keeper dies, all those in the know become secret-keepers:

> Mr. Weasley had explained that after the death of Dumbledore, their
>   Secret-Keeper, each of the people to whom Dumbledore had confided Grimmauld
>   Place’s location had become a Secret People in turn.

And since the Leaky Cauldron had to be pointed out to Harry, it seems something similar is happening here - it's like a Fidelius charm where everyone's the secret-keeper.

And we know Muggles can enter the Leaky Cauldron:

> “So you don’t think I’m a match for Lucius Malfoy?” said Mr.
>   Weasley indignantly, but he was distracted almost at once by the
>   sight of Hermione’s parents, who were standing nervously at the
>   counter that ran all along the great marble hall, waiting for
>   Hermione to introduce them.

So, since we know Muggles can access the Leaky Cauldron (which seems similar to a Fidelius charm after the Secret-Keeper dies, and thus explains why Harry had to get it pointed out by Hagrid), and yet there are no fears of Muggles revealing the location of the Leaky Cauldron to others, it seems that Muggles cannot be Secret Keepers.

Yes, its speculative, but a good guess considering what we know.

Of course this whole answer depends on how literally you take the words

> If Hagrid hadn't pointed it out, Harry wouldn't have noticed it was there.

If its just an expression, the whole answer falls apart.

Comment: We know of many forms of 'Muggle-repelling' effects that shield things from Muggle sight.  For instance, Hogwarts itself looks to Muggles like an old, run-down ruin with a 'Condemned' sign on the gate.  It's much more likely to be something like the 'notice-me-not' charm we've seen referenced than a wide-scale Fidelius, especially given that the F. charm makes things Unplottable, too.

Comment: Almost all notice-me-not charms conceal the building as a ruin or similar. The Fidelius charm is the only charm we know of that invisibalizes the building completely.

Comment: @Jeff - Pretty sure that Fidelius doesn't make things unplottable. Notice how Sirius lists them as two separate things when discussing Grimmauld Place.